# Is there any condition when making high volume community user becomes compulsory?

Tags: community, customer-community, salesforce-classic, high-volume-portal

What i mean is that is there any condition when we can only create high volume community user and not community normal user something like that?

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the help article [About High-Volume Community Users](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5), you will get most of your answers.

> High-volume community users are limited-access users intended for orgs that have thousands to millions of communities users.

There's no condition as such when you create such users instead of regular community users. It depends on your use case and needs planning to identify what will be your community user size. Then such users have limitations which needs to be considered depending on your use case.  Based on those factors you decide if you want to create a high volume or regular community user.